# How to use CAML queris in InfoPath 2010 List Forms

Tags: infopath

Is it possible to run CAML queris in InfoPath 2010 List form?
I want to populate a dropdown based on the selection done in another dropdown.

Tanks.

Answer (score 1):

Depending upon your scenario, you may be able to achieve this without involving CAML. There are so many articles/blogs on this topic: "Caacading dropdowns with infopath 2007/2010" on the web. See if those help.